# How to resize icons in Mac Finder with keyboard

Tags: macos, icons, finder

I work a lot with images, and often find myself resizing the image icon thumbs. This is tolerable but not ideal with the trackpad, but I'd like to do it via the keyboard.

I've looked but have been unable to find a built-in keyboard shortcut to do this.

Is there a built-in method to do this? If not, can someone help me find the right commands to do this in a script or service?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the pinch and zoom gesture on the trackpad? I'm almost positive there's some gesture to achieve this.

Comment: There's also this method in macOS. *When “Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom” is selected, you can zoom in by pressing and holding the Control key (or another modifier key) and swiping up with two fingers on your trackpad.* You can check [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25218?viewlocale=en_GU&locale=en_GU) for more info.

Comment: @DrZoo No dice with this, and the second reference only works for "zooming" not sizing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the OP still needs it, but I came here looking for the answer myself, so I'll post what I found:

<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> - make icons bigger.

<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> - make icons smaller.

Tested on Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game here but, in an open folder, if you press command - or + (- and =), you can toggle between the small and large. Or command J, change the icon size and the set as default at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, works in Big Sur.